# Python IDLE error in an outside function

Tags: python, function, return

There's an outside function but I don't know where. IDLE say it's at line 37. When I move the return statement, Python says it's indented but sometimes it says it's an outside function. 
I'm looking through the Python manual for detail.

```
def move () :
    while True:
        print
        player = raw_imput ("Pierre = 1 \nPapier = 2\nCiseaux = 3\nQuel est ton choix?: ")
    try:
        player = int(player)
        if player in (1,2,3):
            return player
    except (ValueError):
        pass   
    print ( "Mince ! Je n'ai pas compris. S'il vous pla?t entrer 1,2 ou 3. " )
```

Comment: Could you please post the exact error the IDE is complaining? Also: which line in your code would be line 37?

Comment: Thanks but i fix the error

Comment: Please consider closing/deleting this question if you've already solved it. It seem trivial and not of any value to the SO community.

Comment: Also consider posting your fix as an answer to your own question.

Comment: formatted the code, added clarity

Answer (score 0):

Your code has broken indentation. The `try:` for example needs to be indented Otherwise the scope of the function will end and `return` later will seem to be outside a function.

```
def move () :
    while True:
        print
        player = raw_imput ("Pierre = 1 \nPapier = 2\nCiseaux = 3\nQuel est ton choix?: ")
try:
#^ This try here is on the same level as "def". This means that it is _outside_ the function.
```